# performSelectorInBackground having access to UI

Tags: ios, multithreading

I have an iOS app. It checks the network connectivity in the main thread. Sometimes, it's blocking. So I forked out a child thread to do the network check in the new code. Interestingly, the child thread is able to popup an alert window. I thought all UI is controlled by the main thread only. Any ideas?

**old code:**

```
Reachability *m_checkReachability=[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.xxx.edu"];
```

**new code:**

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(checkConnectivity) withObject:nil]; 

(void)checkConnectivity{ 
    Reachability *m_checkReachability=[Reachability  reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.xxx.edu"]; 

if (![m_checkReachability isReachable]) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Network is not availabe. Do you want to close the app?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; 

    [alert show]; 
}
```

I know the performSelectorInBackground is an old way. Just try to understand why it's still having the control to UI, which should belong to the master thread?

Comment: It's actually a bad practice to call UI thread from a background thread. But surprisingly it is perfectly acceptable in most of the cases.

Comment: I know it's bad. I am just surprised that iOS even allows it.

Comment: Yes iOS allows this but not in a thread safe manner. UIKit should(must) run on main thread(and queue since GCD is concerned). Calling UIKit from background thread has an undefined behavior and that means it can cause every bad thing to the running app if another thread is using the same memory block of UIKit at the same instance of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just bad code that is likely to cause trouble. The compiler doesn't know that the code could make UI calls from a background thread, so it happily compiles the code. The solution would be to call the UI on the main thread.

Comment: It's not just the compiler. The code got executed as well. At least in the XCode.